# Is there a way to make leather armor stronger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to use a command to make leather armor stronger than diamond armor?

Making it harder to break?

Comment: When you say "stronger" do you mean that it blocks more damage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done with a command block.

```
/give {name} minecraft:command_block
```

This will give the nearest player a Leather chestplate with the enchant Unbreaking level 32767 (max) (the Unbreaking enchantment ID is 34) and the lore (thing underneath) will say "May these protect you".

```
/give @p minecraft:leather_chestplate 1 0 {display:{Name:"PutNameHere",Lore:["May these protect you"]},ench:[{id:34s,lvl:32767s}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this command, you will not need a command block, and this command will make the armor completely unbreakable.
Here's the command:

```
/give @p minecraft:leather_chestplate 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}
```

Explained:

```
/give                          give
@p                             the nearest player
minecraft:leather_chestplate   a leather chestplate 
1                              one time  
0                              and make it have no damage  
{Unbreakable:1}                and make it unbreakable
```

This will be resistant to anything when a player is wearing it, even though you will still be taking damage through it, and, sadly, the item will still be damageable *(example: you can burn the item)*.

Comment: Hey, you stole [my formatting trick](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258501/how-to-detect-the-winner/292463#292463)! :)

Comment: @user143228 nah.